# Is there a bar at Incheon airport?

Tags: airports, food-and-drink, south-korea, alcohol, icn

Is there a bar at Incheon International Airport, Korea (ICN)?

I know there are 7-11s etc where you can buy a can and sit at a table, but I'm looking for a bar and some draught beer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Heineken Bar at Incheon Airport

The [Incheon Airport webpage mentions Heineken Bar](http://www.cyberairport.kr/pa/en/a/5/6/index.jsp#), one in the East and one in the West side of the duty free area, both next to gate 4F. I don't know if they have draught beer, but the name looks promising. Below is a screenshot from the linked site:

[image: Incheon Bar Heineken]

#### The Jet Lagged Lizard at Incheon

A couple hundred metres outside of the airport, in Incheon, you can also find the [Jet Lagged Lizard](http://www.thejetlaggedlizard.com/Home.html) - a full blown pub with draught beer, food and all the rest. This solutions looks perfect, provided you are willing to leave the airport terminal. [According to google maps, the logistics on how to get there are pretty straightforward.](https://goo.gl/maps/wytn8)

Answer (score 1):

Yup, at heiniken bar now.  The only beer they sell is heiniken.  They sell coffee and some food items.  Well, it's called heineken bar.

Comment: This seems more like a comment on the answer above than an answer in itself. It could easily be expanded in to an answer however.